# sendATCommand not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gps, gsm, modem, tracker

it is arduino program for GSM and GPS modem. In this GPS modem send the location to user with the help of GSM modem but getting this error continuously.

here the program
I'm getting this again and again even after some changes for the program 
ATCommand is for the SIM908 Module 
    int8_t answer;

```
int onModulePin= 2; 
char aux_string[30]; 
int flag = 0;

char number [20]; 
char realnumber[9]; 
char mynumber[9]; 

int a=0;
int b=0; 
int c=0;

//Your phone number

char phone_number[]="85274****5";


char data[100]; 
int data_size;
char aux_str[30]; 
char aux;

int x = 0; 
char N_S,W_E;



char frame[200];
char latitude[15];  
char longitude[15]; 
char altitude[6]; 
char date[16];

char time[7]; 

char satellites[3]; 
char speedOTG[10]; 
 char course[10];


void setup(){ 
  mynumber[0]='8'; 
  mynumber[1]='5'; 
  mynumber[2]='2'; 
  mynumber[3]='7'; 
  mynumber[4]='4'; 
  mynumber[5]='*'; 
  mynumber[6]='*'; 
  mynumber[7]='*'; 
  mynumber[8]='*'; 
  mynumber[9]='5';


  pinMode(onModulePin, OUTPUT); Serial.begin(115200);



  delay(5000);


   sendATcommand("AT+CPIN=****", "OK", 2000);


   delay(3000);


   while( (sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 1000) ||         sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,5", 1000)) == 0 );


   sendATcommand("AT+CLIP=1", "OK", 1000);


   while ( start_GPS() == 0);


   while (sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 2000) == 0);


   // sets APN , user name and password          
   sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"","OK", 2000); 
   sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"*******\"", "OK",2000); 
   sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"USER\",\"*******\"","OK", 2000); 
   sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"PWD\",\"*******\"", "OK",2000);


   // gets the GPRS bearer

   while (sendATcommand("AT+SAPBR=1,1", "OK", 20000) == 0)

  {

  delay(5000);

   }


  delay(1000);

   while(Serial.available() != 0)

  {

   Serial.read();

   }

  }

  void loop(){


  answer = sendATcommand("", "+CLIP", 1000);  //Detect incomming call

   if (answer == 1)

 {

  Serial.println("Incoming call");


  if ( flag == 0){


  for (int i=0; i<19; i++){ // read the incoming byte:


  while (Serial.available() == 0)

{

 delay (50);

 }

 //Stores phone number number[i] = Serial.read();


 }

Serial.flush(); flag = 1;

 }

   //Stores phone calling number  for (int i=0; i<=14; i++){

 if(number[i]== '"'){       i++;
 realnumber[0]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[1]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[2]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[3]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[4]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[5]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[6]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[7]=number[i]; i++; 
 realnumber[8]=number[i];

 break;

 }

}


  //Check phone number  for (int i=0;i<9;i++){

if (realnumber[i] == mynumber[i]){ a++;

if( a==9){

 Serial.println("Correct number"); sendATcommand("ATH", "OK", 1000);

if(b==1){ b=0;
}else{ b=1; c=1; 
 }  

 break;

}

}else{

 Serial.println("Wrong number");  break;

}

}

a=0; answer=0; flag = 0;

}

 //Send SMS once and position to HTTP if (b==1){

 get_GPS(); send_HTTP(); delay(500);

 if (c==1){ sendSMS(); delay(100);

c=0;

 }

 }


 }


void power_on(){


 uint8_t answer=0;


 digitalWrite(onModulePin,HIGH); delay(3000); 
  digitalWrite(onModulePin,LOW);

 while (answer ==  0 ){  // Send AT every two seconds
 and wait for the  answer  

 answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);

   }

 }


 int8_t sendATcommand(char* ATcommand, char* expected_answer, unsigned int    timeout){


uint8_t x=0, answer=0;  char response[100];  unsigned long previous;

    memset(response,  '\0'  , 100 );        // Initialice the string                                 
    delay(100);                        
   while ( Serial.available() > 0 ) Serial.read(); //Clean the input buffer        
   if (ATcommand[ 0  ] != '\0'   )         

   {                                         

    Serial.println(ATcommand);        
     }

   x = 0;
   previous = millis();


   // this loop waits for the answer  do{

  if(Serial.available() != 0){ // if there are data in the UART input   buffer, reads it and checks for the asnwer

 response[x] = Serial.read();  //Serial.print(response[x]);

 x++;

 if (strstr(response, expected_answer) != NULL) // check if the desired answer (OK) is in the response of the module

{

answer = 1;

}

}

}while((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) <timeout));  // Waits for the asnwer with time out


  return answer;

  }


  void power_onGPS(){

  uint8_t answer=0;    // checks if the module is started

  answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);  if (answer == 0)

  {

 // power on pulse
 digitalWrite(onModulePin,HIGH); delay(3000); digitalWrite(onModulePin,LOW);

  // waits for an answer from the module while(answer == 0){

  // Send AT every two seconds and wait for the answer

  answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);

 }

 }


 }


 int8_t start_GPS(){


 unsigned long previous;


 previous = millis();  // starts the GPS

  sendATcommand("AT+CGPSPWR=1", "OK", 2000); sendATcommand("AT+CGPSRST=0", "OK", 2000);

 // waits for fix GPS

 while(( (sendATcommand("AT+CGPSSTATUS?", "2D Fix", 5000) ||

 sendATcommand("AT+CGPSSTATUS?", "3D Fix", 5000)) ==0 ) &&

((millis() - previous) < 90000)); 


if ((millis() - previous) < 90000)

{

 return 1;

}

else

{

return 0;

 }  

}


int8_t get_GPS(){


int8_t counter, answer;  long previous;


// First get the NMEA string  // Clean the input buffer

 while( Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();  // request Basic string

sendATcommand("AT+CGPSINF=0", "AT+CGPSINF=0\r\n\r\n", 2000);


 counter = 0; answer = 0;

 memset(frame, '\0', 100); // Initialize the string previous = millis();

 // this loop waits for the NMEA string  do{


 if(Serial.available() != 0){ frame[counter] = Serial.read(); counter++;

 // check if the desired answer is in the response of the module

 if (strstr(frame, "OK") != NULL)

{

answer = 1;

}

}

// Waits for the asnwer with time out


}

 while((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) < 2000));


frame[counter-3] = '\0';


// Parses the string strtok(frame, ",");

strcpy(longitude,strtok(NULL, ",")); // Gets longitude     
strcpy(latitude,strtok(NULL, ",")); // Gets latitude    
strcpy(altitude,strtok(NULL, ".")); // Gets altitude 
strtok(NULL, ",");

strcpy(date,strtok(NULL, ".")); // Gets date strtok(NULL, ",");

strtok(NULL, ","); strcpy(satellites,strtok(NULL, ",")); // Gets satellites

strcpy(speedOTG,strtok(NULL, ",")); // Gets speed over ground. Unit is knots.

strcpy(course,strtok(NULL, "\r")); // Gets course


 convert2Degrees(latitude);

  convert2Degrees(longitude);


 return answer;

 }


  /* convert2Degrees ( input ) - performs the conversion from input

 * parameters in DD°MM.mmm’ notation to DD.dddddd° notation.


 * Sign '+' is set for positive latitudes/longitudes (North, East)

* Sign '-' is set for negative latitudes/longitudes (South, West)


*/

int8_t convert2Degrees(char* input){


float deg;

float minutes; boolean neg = false;  //auxiliar variable  char aux[10];

if (input[0] == '-')

{

 neg = true;

 strcpy(aux, strtok(input+1, "."));


 }

 else

 {

  strcpy(aux, strtok(input, "."));

  }  // convert string to integer and add it to final float variable

  deg = atof(aux);


  strcpy(aux, strtok(NULL, '\0')); minutes=atof(aux); minutes/=1000000;
  if (deg < 100)

  {

   minutes += deg; deg = 0;

  }

   else


 {

  minutes += int(deg) % 100; deg = int(deg) / 100;

 } // add minutes to degrees deg=deg+minutes/60;

 if (neg == true)

{

 deg*=-1.0;

}


neg = false;


if( deg < 0 ){ neg = true; deg*=-1;

}


 float numberFloat=deg;  int intPart[10];

 int digit;

 long newNumber=(long)numberFloat;  int size=0;


 while(1){ size=size+1; digit=newNumber%10;
 newNumber=newNumber/10; intPart[size-1]=digit;

 if (newNumber==0){  break;

}

}


int index=0;

if( neg ){ index++; input[0]='-';

}

for (int i=size-1; i >= 0; i--)

{

input[index]=intPart[i]+'0'; index++;

}


input[index]='.'; index++;


numberFloat=(numberFloat-(int)numberFloat);  for (int i=1; i<=6 ; i++)

{

numberFloat=numberFloat*10; digit= (long)numberFloat;  numberFloat=numberFloat-digit; input[index]=char(digit)+48; index++;
}

 input[index]='\0';


 }


 void send_HTTP(){


 uint8_t answer=0; // Initializes HTTP service

answer = sendATcommand("AT+HTTPINIT", "OK", 10000);  if (answer == 1)

{ // Sets CID parameter

answer = sendATcommand("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1", "OK", 5000);
if (answer == 1)

{

 // Sets url sprintf(aux_str,

 "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://%s/demo_sim908.php?", url);     Serial.print(aux_str);

 sprintf(frame,

"visor=false&latitude=%s&longitude=%s&altitude=%s&time=%s&s atellites=%s&speedOTG=%s&course=%s",

latitude, longitude, altitude, date, satellites, speedOTG, course);

 Serial.print(frame);

 answer = sendATcommand("\"", "OK", 5000);  if (answer == 1)

 {

  // Starts GET action

  answer = sendATcommand("AT+HTTPACTION=0", "+HTTPACTION:0,200", 30000);
  if (answer == 1)

 {


  Serial.println(F("Done!"));

 }

  else

  {

  Serial.println(F("Error getting url"));

  }


   }

 else

 {

 Serial.println(F("Error setting the url"));



 }

 }

 else

 {

 Serial.println(F("Error setting the CID"));

 }

 }

 else

 {

  Serial.println(F("Error initializating"));

  }


  sendATcommand("AT+HTTPTERM", "OK", 5000);


  }


  void power_onSMS(){

  uint8_t answer=0; // checks if the module is started

  answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);  if (answer == 0)

  {

    // power on pulse digitalWrite(onModulePin,HIGH); delay(3000); digitalWrite(onModulePin,LOW);

   // waits for  an  answer from the module
   while       
    (answer ==  0    ){    

     answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);

       }

     }

      }


      void sendSMS(){ sendATcommand("AT+CPIN=****", "OK", 2000);


     delay(3000);


   Serial.println("Connecting to the network...");


   while( (sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 500) ||   sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,5", 500))




  Serial.print("Setting SMS mode..."); sendATcommand("AT+CMGF=1", "OK", 1000); // sets theSMS mode to text 
   Serial.println("Sending SMS");


  sprintf(aux_string,"AT+CMGS=\"%s\"", phone_number); answer = sendATcommand(aux_string, ">", 2000); //

 send the SMS number  if (answer == 1)

 {

   Serial.print("Theft Alert:");

   Serial.print("Latitude: ");  int i = 0;  while(latitude[i]!=0){

  Serial.print(latitude[i]);

  i++;

 }

 Serial.print(" / Longitude: "); i = 0;

 while(longitude[i]!=0){ Serial.print(longitude[i]);


i++;

}

Serial.write(0x1A);

answer = sendATcommand("", "OK", 20000);  if (answer == 1)

{

Serial.print("Sent ");

}

 else

{

 Serial.print("error ");

}

 }

 else

{

Serial.print("error "); Serial.println(answer, DEC);

 }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as no one likes to read several pages of code to find your particular error. In this case it is rather obvious (You use the function before declaring it) but this is not always true.

Comment: ```#include "Sim908.h"``` I guess

Comment: The whole code is given for reference if any body is interested but you can see the error in picture and i have used the command many times above this where there is no error but in this statement it called a error

Answer (score 0):

If you move function

```
int8_t sendATcommand(char* ATcommand, char* expected_answer, unsigned int    timeout)
```

before first usage (before setup() function) it should work.

Comment: if I insert this statement then it will change the sendATcommand to be a defined dunction while in further i need to change that to char which will be a issue